# Inequality involving series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(\alpha_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ an increasing sequence of real numbers such that : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}, \, \alpha_{n} > 0$ and $\alpha_{0} = 0$ and $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} \alpha_{n}=+\infty$. Let $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of non-negative real numbers. We define :

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}, \, v_{n} = \Big( \frac{1}{\alpha_{n}} - \frac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}} \Big) \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k}u_{k} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad w_{n} = \frac{1}{\alpha_{n}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k}u_{k}. $$

I have shown that :

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, n \geq 2, \, \sum_{k=1}^{n} u_{k} = w_{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} v_{k}. \tag{1}$$

Now we assume that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 1} v_{n}$ converges. I would like to prove that :

$$ w_{n} \leq \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} v_{k} $$

---

Here is what I tried : for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq 2$,

$$ w_{n} - \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} v_{k} = w_{n} - \Big( \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} v_{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} v_{k} \Big) $$

Therefore :

$$ w_{n} - \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} v_{k} = \underbrace{\Big( w_{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} v_{k} \Big)}_{ = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} u_{k} } - \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} v_{k}. $$

As a consequence, the inequality holds if I can prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} u_{k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} v_{k}$. But this does not seem that easy to prove. Is there another way ?

**Edit** : for $k \geq 1$

$$ 
\begin{align*} v_{k} & = {} \frac{1}{\alpha_{k}} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \alpha_{j}u_{j} - \frac{1}{\alpha_{k+1}} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \alpha_{j}u_{j} \\
 &= \frac{1}{\alpha_{k}} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \alpha_{j}u_{j} - \frac{1}{\alpha_{k+1}} \Big( \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} \alpha_{j}u_{j} - \alpha_{k+1}u_{k+1} \Big) \\
&= \underbrace{\frac{1}{\alpha_{k}} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \alpha_{j}u_{j}}_{=\beta_{k}} - \underbrace{\frac{1}{\alpha_{k+1}} \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} \alpha_{j}u_{j}}_{=\beta_{k+1}} + u_{k+1} \\
\end{align*} $$

Then, for $N \geq n$ :

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N} v_{k} = u_{1} - \beta_{N+1} + \sum_{k=2}^{N+1} u_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} u_{k} + \Big( \sum_{k=n+1}^{N+1} u_{k} - \frac{1}{\alpha_{N+1}} \sum_{j=1}^{N+1} \alpha_{j}u_{j} \Big) $$

Can this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost done: 
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{N+1} u_{k} - \frac{1}{\alpha_{N+1}} \sum_{j=1}^{N+1} \alpha_{j}u_{j} =\sum_{k=n+1}^{N+1}u_k\left(1-\frac{\alpha_k}{\alpha_{N+1}}\right)-\frac 1{\alpha_{N+1}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_ju_j.$$
Since $(\alpha_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ is increasing, we have for each $N,n$, 
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{N+1}u_k\left(1-\frac{\alpha_k}{\alpha_{N+1}}\right)\geqslant 0,$$
hence for $N\geqslant n$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^Nv_k\geqslant \sum_{k=1}^nu_k-\frac 1{\alpha_{N+1}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_ju_j.$$
Now, for a fix $n$, let $N\to +\infty$ to get the wanted inequality.